# Explain Line: $foo = isset($_POST['foo']) ? $_POST['foo'] : '';

Tags: php, validation

Can someone explain this line to me, so I can understand it?

To my knowledge:

`$foo = isset($_POST['foo'])` - Is checking to see if `$_POST['foo']` is actually set.

But what does the `? $_POST['foo'] : '';` mean?

Comment: it's a ternary operator http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's simple to explain: `if_monday() ? "coffee" : "tea"`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Can you explain a little? I'm still fairly new to PHP, and I want to make sure I understand it.

Comment: `define('tea', 'cappuccino');` @Rizier123 ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- So... Let me see if I understand:  `$foo = isset($_POST['foo'] ? $_POST['foo'] : ' ';` is the same as saying `if (isset ($_POST['foo'])) { $foo = $_POST['foo'];} else {$foo = ' ';}`

Comment: exactly; let's call it *"shorthand"* ;-)